# Словарь не приходит в цикл шаблона Django

Tags: python, django

index.html

```
{% for pos in posts %}
        <article>
          <ul>
            <li>
              Место: {{ pos.location }}
            </li>
            <li>
              Дата: {{ pos.date }}
            </li>
            <li>
              Категория: <a href="not-my-day">{{ pos.category }}</a>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <p>
            {{ pos.text|truncatewords:10 }}
          </p>
          <a href="{% url 'blog.post_detail' pk=id %}" >Читать полный текст</a>
        </article>
    {% endfor %}
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [
path('', views.index, name='index', ),
path('<int:id>/', views.post_detail, name='post_detail'),
path('<slug:category_slug>/', views.category_post, name='category_post'),]
```

view.py

```
def post_detail(request, id):
template = 'index.html'
context = {'posts': posts[id]}
return render(request, template, context)
```

В файле view.py так же присутствует словарь, почему он не передается в шаблон?
Так же не могу найти причину, почему адрес страницы в браузере выглядит таким образом: http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/about/, ходя должен быть таким http://127.0.0.1:8000/about/